# View the waiting/suspended queries between a time period in the past

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to optimize an SQL process using the dmv `([sys].[dm_os_wait_stats])`.

*Is there any way that we can see the waiting/suspended queries between a time period in the past?*. Like want to have records only from 3pm today.

Currently I clean the instance every time before running the process using

```
DBCC SQLPERF ('sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR);
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that using monitoring tools such as [Idera](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver) or [Redgate monitor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/) in order to monitor sql server waiting. You can also copy ([sys].[dm_os_wait_stats]) data in other table periodically.